# How to get latest NVIDIA P100 GRID driver for GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

I own a Windows Server 2019 GUI virtual machine, with a P100 driver.

The problem is that some of my games requires the latest NVIDIA P100 driver, 442.29, but the latest driver released by GCE is 442.06 (there: https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-eu-public/)

Do I have to wait for them to update it ? If yes, how much time ? Thanks !

Comment: Given that you aready provide all the info that there is - what do you expect us to do? Provide you with an unreleased answer and/or telling you a fixed date for a driver release? ASK NVIDIA.

Comment: The driver is already released by NVIDIA, I can download it and install it, but the GPU wont work anymore, unless I downgrade it to one of the version listed on the link above. READ PLEASE.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#windows-driver-steps). Do you use [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)? Please run `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe` and update your question with output before drivers upgrade and after.

Comment: @AymeneB No, you say the current driver released is too old. Now you say it is released. But in my school i Learned that 442.06 is not the same driver but an older compared to 442.29. So, what is right now? You contradict yourself.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by my own: GRID version of this driver is not yet available, only 442.29 NON GRID version is.